# Totient and division

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that if the arguments are relatively prime, I can write

$$
\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)
$$

can I conclude that if $b\mid a$

$$
\frac{\phi(a)}{\phi(b)}=\phi(\frac{a}{b})
$$

Thanks

Comment: $a/b$ isn't even an integer in general.  If it is they $a$ and $b$ are certainly not relatively prime.

Comment: You will need that $b\mid a$, hence they are no longer comprime.

Comment: Let me fix the question, then.

Comment: How do you define $\phi(\frac{a}{b})$ if $b$ does not divide $a$?

Answer (score 2):

No, let $a = bk$. you claim only holds true if $\gcd(b,k) = 1$. Otherwise, there are some extra products on the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

No.$\let\phi\varphi$ The assertion $\frac{\phi(a)}{\phi(b)}=\phi(\tfrac ab)$ is equivalent to **complete multiplicativeness**: Let $a=bk$, then it says
$$\phi(bk)=\phi(b)\phi(k)\qquad\text{for arbitrary }b,k$$
which would mean that $\phi$ is completely multiplicative, which it is not. It is only true if $\gcd(b,k)=1$.